# How can I force @angular/core to use the latest version of zone.js in its peerDependencies configuration?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, jasmine, zonejs

This test passes but results in a problem:

```
it('should retrieve data on getDownloadProgress() call', (done: DoneFn) => {
    let response = {
        'process': {},
        'success': 'success',
    } as IPollResponse;
    
    httpClientSpy.get.and.returnValue(of(response));

    service.getDownloadProgress(1)!.subscribe((result: any) => {
        expect(result).toEqual(response);
        done();
    });
});
```

There is an error that displays when running tests in Jasmine and it falsely indicates test failure:

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
Error: An asynchronous spec, beforeEach, or afterEach function called its 'done' callback more than once.
```

The bug that causes this error is fixed in the latest version of `zone.js` according to this thread:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45476

`@angular/core` depends on `zone.js` version `0.11.4` in its `peerDependencies` which is revealed in `package-lock.json`:

```
    "node_modules/@angular/core": {
        "version": "14.2.7",
        "license": "MIT",
        "dependencies": {
            "tslib": "^2.3.0"
        },
        "engines": {
            "node": "^14.15.0 || >=16.10.0"
        },
        "peerDependencies": {
            "rxjs": "^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0",
            "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
        }
    },
```

I believe that if I can force `@angular/core` to use the latest version of `zone.js` this error will stop appearing.

How can I force `@angular/core` to use a specific version of `zone.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if forcing `@angular/core` to use a specific version of `zone.js` is a good idea because a different version may fix this problem but it can create other problems. There could be a good reason that `@angular/core` wants that version of `zone.js`.

To fix your issue, usually in Angular unit tests, I make sure I unsubscribe from the subscriptions especially if they are not one and done.

Try something like this to fix your issue:

```
service.getDownloadProgress(1)!.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((result: any) => {
        expect(result).toEqual(response);
        done();
    });
```

The `take(1)` operator will only take one emission and call the callback and therefore `done()` should only be called once.